# Residue for $\frac{e^z+1}{\sin z}$

Tags: residue-calculus

I want to find the residue of $\displaystyle f=\frac{e^z+1}{\sin z}$ at $z=0$.

My solution was $2$, which I got using $\displaystyle \frac{e^z+1}{\sin z}=\frac{e^z}{\sin z}+\frac{1}{\sin z}$.

The residue for $\displaystyle Res_0\left( \frac{1}{\sin z} \right)=\lim_{z\rightarrow 0}z\frac{1}{\sin z}=\lim_{z\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{\cos z}=1$

The residue for $\displaystyle Res_0\left( \frac{e^z}{\sin z} \right)=\lim_{z\rightarrow 0}z\frac{e^z}{\sin z}=\lim_{z\rightarrow 0}\frac{e^z+ze^z}{\cos z}=1$

Adding up the residues, the answer would be $2$.

Another question I have is regarding the order of residues. I know that for $\displaystyle \frac{a}{z^n}$ the order is $n$, but what happens with non-polynomials function like trigonometric in my case? I assumed the order of $0$ in $\displaystyle\frac{1}{\sin z}$ to be $1$, but I am not sure of what argument I could give here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the Taylor series expansion of $\exp$ and $\sin$ to determine the residue. It is convenient to  use the Landau  *[Big-O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)*.

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{e^z+1}{\sin z}&=\frac{2+O(z)}{z+O(z^3)}\tag{1}\\
> &=\frac{2}{z}\left(\frac{1+O(z)}{1+O(z^2)}\right)\tag{2}\\
> &=\frac{2}{z}(1+O(z))(1+O(z^2))\tag{3}\\
> &=\frac{2}{z}(1+O(z))
> \end{align*}
>   and it  follows
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\mathrm{Res}_0\left( \frac{e^z+1}{\sin z} \right)=2}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we expand $e^z=1+z+\frac{z}{2}+\cdots=1+O(z)$ and $\sin z=z-\frac{z^3}{3!}+\cdots=z+O(z^3)$.
- In (2) we factor out $\frac{2}{z}$.
- In (3) we use the *[geometric series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Geometric_power_series)* and obtain $$\frac{1}{1+O(z^2)}=1+O(z^2)+O(z^4)+\cdots=1+O(z^2)$$

Answer (score 1):

The function has a pole of order $1$ at $0$, because
$$
\lim_{z\to 0}z\frac{e^z+1}{\sin z}=2
$$
Thus the residue is $2$.

If you don't believe it, write
$$
\frac{e^z+1}{\sin z}=\frac{a_{-1}}{z}+a_0+a_1z+\dotsb
$$
and compute this way the limit above.